# Adding extra to all records in a column

Tags: excel

I have an excel file that contains in A1 2800 records.
I need to add in front of all these records 0000 how is it possible please to do that
so i don't have manualy to add one by one?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

first, hit `alt d e` to bring up the "convert text to columns wizard". split your data accordingly.

then, check out the `format` function or just do `="0000" & A1` and copy it down/over

Comment: it's a little bit difficult to me.. is it possible sir to user teamviewer to show me? Thank you!

Comment: sorry, can't do that. if you're confused, check out google on "delimiting text in excel" and then the second part is straightforward, just try it out on a sample cell and see what you get.